# Como passar como parâmetro num método em 'items' de um forEach, uma variável da URL?

Tags: java, jsp

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Java, trabalho acadêmico. Minha dúvida está no seguinte. Eu consigo exibir os itens relacionados a um usuário logado, onde o valor(nick) é setado numa sessão com nome login.
Veja:

```
<jsp:useBean id="dao" class="dao.CestaDAO" />
<c:forEach var="item" items="${dao.findItens(login)}">
  ${item.nome}
</c:forEach>
```

Tudo rola perfeitamente. Porém, estou com problema quando como administrador, ao clicar num link que passa uma variável via URL(?clienteLogin=fulano). Não consigo pegar o valor possado e jogar como parâmetro, em findItens(). Devo estar cometendo um erro bobo, Java não é a linguagem que domino. Obrigado!

```
String cliente=request.getParameter("clienteLogin").toString();

<jsp:useBean id="dao" class="dao.CestaDAO" />
<c:forEach var="item" items="${dao.findItens(cliente)}">
  ${item.nome}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, consegui resolver usando *sessionScope*. Só assim foi possível setar o atributo(cliente) e utiliza-lo como parâmetro em *${dao.findItens(cliente)}*.

```
         <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${sessionScope.login != null && sessionScope.login ne 'admin'}">
                <% pageContext.setAttribute("cliente", String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("login")), PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
                %>
            </c:when>

            <c:when test="${sessionScope.login == 'admin'}">

                <% pageContext.setAttribute("cliente", String.valueOf(request.getParameter("clienteLogin")), PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
                %>
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>

        <h1>Lista de  ${sessionScope.cliente}</h1>

        <jsp:useBean id="dao" class="dao.CestaDAO" />
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${dao.findItens(cliente)}">
                <li>${item.nome}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
```